# Subset command in R

Tags: r

From a set of observations, I would like to select the values that are greater than zero **but at the same time** lower than 2. I have tried the command:

```
ysub<-subset(y,y>=0,y<=2)
```

but unfortunately this brings negative values as well! How can I make sure the intersection is taken into account?

This is probably a trivial question but the `?subset` page seems vague, thank you.

Comment: Have a look at `?'&'` on how to combine your conditions.

Comment: Since I have this URL in my clipboard: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html :)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I will work on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a "&" between the subset calls.

```
a <- rnorm(11,5,2)
y <- c(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,y))
```

Which gives you:

```
          a  y
1  5.796016 -5
2  1.206939 -4
3  3.071930 -3
4  6.018166 -2
5  6.653600 -1
6  2.916602  0
7  7.966805  1
8  2.681016  2
9  5.219482  3
10 4.558291  4
11 4.426134  5
```

Add "&" to your code:

```
ysub = subset(df,y>=0 & y<=2)
```

And you get:

```
         a y
6 2.916602 0
7 7.966805 1
8 2.681016 2
```